# Why is my DIV not showing on mobile?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to show/hide HTML code based in screen resolution.
I can see the DIV **news_box_desktop** on my desktop computer, but can't see any DIV at all on my mobile (whereas **news_box_mobile** should be visible)
What is the issue?
Thanks,

HTML:

```
<header class="clearfix">
  <a href="index.html" title=""><img class="logo" src="images/blue.png" alt=""></a>
  <div class="menu-container">
    <nav>
      <ul id="menu">
        <li> <a href="index.html">Accueil</a> </li>
        <li class="selected"> <a href="biographie.html">Biographie</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="news_box" class="news_box_desktop" style="position: absolute; bottom:20px; right: 20px; width: 380px; float: right; text-align: left;"></div>
</header>
<div id="news_box" class="news_box_mobile" style="position: relative; width: 90%; margin:auto; left: 0; right: 0; text-align: left;"></div>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) {
.news_box_desktop {
    display: none;
}
.news_box_mobile {
    display: block;
}
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use `px` instead of `em`?

Comment: Your `news_box_mobile` `div` is outside `header` is it like to be that.

Comment: Provide a working example. your code looks fine, just in case max-width 40em in device `.news_box_mobile` should be shown.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: why not cater for a resolution below 40em, like 39.9em as an example. It might be that the emulator (or device) you are using, is seeing the 40em as above that of a mobile display? Just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following changes to make it work properly.

```
header {
  position: relative;       /* so you desktop show inside header */
}
.news_box_mobile {
  display: none;            /* so your mobile is hidden by default */
}
```

May I also recommend you put all your CSS external (I did that for you in below sample) as it will bring simpler maintenance, reuse of rules and cleaner markup.

```css
header {
  position: relative;       /* so you desktop show inside header */
}
.news_box_mobile {
  display: none;            /* so your mobile is hidden by default */
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  margin:auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.news_box_desktop {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:20px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 380px;
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) {
  .news_box_desktop {
    display: none;
  }
  .news_box_mobile {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="clearfix">
  <a href="index.html" title=""><img class="logo" src="images/blue.png" alt=""></a>
  <div class="menu-container">
    <nav>
      <ul id="menu">
        <li> <a href="index.html">Accueil</a> </li>
        <li class="selected"> <a href="biographie.html">Biographie</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="news_box" class="news_box_desktop">desktop</div>
</header>
<div id="news_box" class="news_box_mobile">mobile</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Actually it seems to look exactly the same as my initial code, but for some reason the news_box_mobile does not show up (this is not an issue with the @media because the other parameters are applied). Can you please take a look at the live page and let me know if you are able to identify what the issue is? Many thanks! http://urlgone.com/ac72d8/

Comment: @Greg After a quick look I see 2 things, 1: `#news_box_mobile {...}` - this rule target an id, not your class ...2: The content of your `news_box_mobile` div is empty so there is nothing to see ... So may I suggest you color the background and give it a size, or add a text to it, and you likely will see it in the page

Comment: @Greg You can of course use the dev.tools, look it up and manipulate its settings to see where and how it shows

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) {
.news_box_desktop {
    display: none;
}
.news_box_mobile {
    display: block;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 40em) {
.news_box_mobile {
    display: none;
}
.news_box_desktop {
    display: block;
}
}
```

Here's [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/kafixabiha/edit?html,css,output), I have checked it's output in my mobile.